# Docker swarm worker nodes bad gateway

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, traefik

I setup Traefik with docker swarm based on this [guide](https://medium.com/@tiangolo/docker-swarm-mode-and-traefik-for-a-https-cluster-20328dba6232). It only worked for single node for the SSL. But I add certificate to my other nodes on swarm.

**Update cert all the nodes**

```
docker node update --label-add traefik-public.traefik-public-certificates=true $NODE_ID
```

**Start Traefik as Manager Role**

```
docker service create \
    --name traefik \
    --constraint=node.labels.traefik-public.traefik-public-certificates==true \
    --constraint=node.role==manager \
    --publish 80:80 \
    --publish 443:443 \
    --mount type=bind,source=/var/run/docker.sock,target=/var/run/docker.sock \
    --mount type=volume,source=traefik-public-certificates,target=/certificates \
    --network traefik-public \
    --label "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:monitor.$DOMAINNAME" \
    --label "traefik.enable=true" \
    --label "traefik.port=8080" \
    --label "traefik.tags=traefik-public" \
    --label "traefik.docker.network=traefik-public" \
    --label "traefik.redirectorservice.frontend.entryPoints=http" \
    --label "traefik.redirectorservice.frontend.redirect.entryPoint=https" \
    --label "traefik.webservice.frontend.entryPoints=https" \
    --label "traefik.frontend.auth.basic.users=${HTTP_USERNAME}:${HASHED_PASSWORD}" \
    traefik:v1.7 \
    --docker \
    --docker.swarmmode \
    --docker.watch \
    --docker.exposedbydefault=false \
    --constraints=tag==traefik-public \
    --entrypoints='Name:http Address::80' \
    --entrypoints='Name:https Address::443 TLS' \
    --acme \
    --acme.email=$EMAIL \
    --acme.storage=/certificates/acme.json \
    --acme.entryPoint=https \
    --acme.httpChallenge.entryPoint=http\
    --acme.onhostrule=true \
    --acme.acmelogging=true \
    --logLevel=INFO \
    --accessLog \
    --api
```

**Docker Node Inspect Worker Node**

```
[
    {
        "ID": "nv15pwb6bie7nvz2yk9uiii10",
        "Version": {
            "Index": 39862
        },
        "CreatedAt": "2019-04-20T09:11:29.540161196Z",
        "UpdatedAt": "2019-04-22T05:37:40.858645073Z",
        "Spec": {
            "Labels": {
                "traefik-public.traefik-public-certificates": "true"
            },
            "Role": "worker",
            "Availability": "active"
        },
        "Description": {
            "Hostname": "node-1",
            "Platform": {
                "Architecture": "x86_64",
                "OS": "linux"
            },
            "Resources": {
                "NanoCPUs": 1000000000,
                "MemoryBytes": 1040351232
            },
            "Engine": {
                "EngineVersion": "18.09.5",
                "Labels": {
                    "provider": "digitalocean"
                },
                "Plugins": [
                    {
                        "Type": "Log",
                        "Name": "awslogs"
                    },
                    {
                        "Type": "Log",
                        "Name": "fluentd"
                    },
                    {
                        "Type": "Log",
                        "Name": "gcplogs"
                    },
                    {
                        "Type": "Log",
                        "Name": "gelf"
                    },
                    {
                        "Type": "Log",
                        "Name": "journald"
                    },
                    {
                        "Type": "Log",
                        "Name": "json-file"
                    },
                    {
                        "Type": "Log",
                        "Name": "local"
                    },
                    {
                        "Type": "Log",
                        "Name": "logentries"
                    },
                    {
                        "Type": "Log",
                        "Name": "splunk"
                    },
                    {
                        "Type": "Log",
                        "Name": "syslog"
                    },
                    {
                        "Type": "Network",
                        "Name": "bridge"
                    },
                    {
                        "Type": "Network",
                        "Name": "host"
                    },
                    {
                        "Type": "Network",
                        "Name": "macvlan"
                    },
                    {
                        "Type": "Network",
                        "Name": "null"
                    },
                    {
                        "Type": "Network",
                        "Name": "overlay"
                    },
                    {
                        "Type": "Volume",
                        "Name": "local"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "TLSInfo": {
                "TrustRoot": "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\nMIIBazCCARCgAwIBAgIUJaJpxCmObYclnve1gMoDgqpbHpYwCgYIKoZIzj0EAwIw\nEzERMA8GA1UEAxMIc3dhcm0tY2EwHhcNMTkwNDIwMDEwMDAwWhcNMzkwNDE1MDEw\nMDAwWjATMREwDwYDVQQDEwhzd2FybS1jYTBZMBMGByqGSM49AgEGCCqGSM49AwEH\nA0IABKZ3tuUh1fbvsBrRxCr/2QpK42UXKH114Y5xUNjCdoVL7sDNJnPqHhGasbXZ\ncuYSf4oFPXau1Euqyo/lHFcn0TqjQjBAMA4GA1UdDwEB/wQEAwIBBjAPBgNVHRMB\nAf8EBTADAQH/MB0GA1UdDgQWBBQLUasL0NneSvfzCIyelreL3Zl8GDAKBggqhkjO\nPQQDAgNJADBGAiEAuPDayJHm8fZEf1yYzS6CtrY/XuRYZK8NuNfG8Xsqs9YCIQDI\nPs6g4c65XPS7Gn931JEC/Qi7Zlu+ccMHy+Eup5SHsQ==\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n",
                "CertIssuerSubject": "MBMxETAPBgNVBAMTCHN3YXJtLWNh",
                "CertIssuerPublicKey": "MFkwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcDQgAEpne25SHV9u+wGtHEKv/ZCkrjZRcofXXhjnFQ2MJ2hUvuwM0mc+oeEZqxtdly5hJ/igU9dq7US6rKj+UcVyfROg=="
            }
        },
        "Status": {
            "State": "ready",
            "Addr": "worker-machine-ip"
        }
    }
]
```

**Docker Node Inspect Manager Node**

```
{
    "ID": "fw4k9vgz7y3929i731o7fll7d",
    "Version": {
        "Index": 39771
    },
    "CreatedAt": "2019-04-20T01:04:39.695763427Z",
    "UpdatedAt": "2019-04-22T05:06:58.875733526Z",
    "Spec": {
        "Labels": {
            "traefik-public.traefik-public-certificates": "true"
        },
        "Role": "manager",
        "Availability": "active"
    },
    "Description": {
        "Hostname": "shijie-master",
        "Platform": {
            "Architecture": "x86_64",
            "OS": "linux"
        },
        "Resources": {
            "NanoCPUs": 1000000000,
            "MemoryBytes": 2097283072
        },
        "Engine": {
            "EngineVersion": "18.09.4",
            "Plugins": [
                {
                    "Type": "Log",
                    "Name": "awslogs"
                },
                {
                    "Type": "Log",
                    "Name": "fluentd"
                },
                {
                    "Type": "Log",
                    "Name": "gcplogs"
                },
                {
                    "Type": "Log",
                    "Name": "gelf"
                },
                {
                    "Type": "Log",
                    "Name": "journald"
                },
                {
                    "Type": "Log",
                    "Name": "json-file"
                },
                {
                    "Type": "Log",
                    "Name": "local"
                },
                {
                    "Type": "Log",
                    "Name": "logentries"
                },
                {
                    "Type": "Log",
                    "Name": "splunk"
                },
                {
                    "Type": "Log",
                    "Name": "syslog"
                },
                {
                    "Type": "Network",
                    "Name": "bridge"
                },
                {
                    "Type": "Network",
                    "Name": "host"
                },
                {
                    "Type": "Network",
                    "Name": "macvlan"
                },
                {
                    "Type": "Network",
                    "Name": "null"
                },
                {
                    "Type": "Network",
                    "Name": "overlay"
                },
                {
                    "Type": "Volume",
                    "Name": "local"
                }
            ]
        },
        "TLSInfo": {
            "TrustRoot": "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\nMIIBazCCARCgAwIBAgIUJaJpxCmObYclnve1gMoDgqpbHpYwCgYIKoZIzj0EAwIw\nEzERMA8GA1UEAxMIc3dhcm0tY2EwHhcNMTkwNDIwMDEwMDAwWhcNMzkwNDE1MDEw\nMDAwWjATMREwDwYDVQQDEwhzd2FybS1jYTBZMBMGByqGSM49AgEGCCqGSM49AwEH\nA0IABKZ3tuUh1fbvsBrRxCr/2QpK42UXKH114Y5xUNjCdoVL7sDNJnPqHhGasbXZ\ncuYSf4oFPXau1Euqyo/lHFcn0TqjQjBAMA4GA1UdDwEB/wQEAwIBBjAPBgNVHRMB\nAf8EBTADAQH/MB0GA1UdDgQWBBQLUasL0NneSvfzCIyelreL3Zl8GDAKBggqhkjO\nPQQDAgNJADBGAiEAuPDayJHm8fZEf1yYzS6CtrY/XuRYZK8NuNfG8Xsqs9YCIQDI\nPs6g4c65XPS7Gn931JEC/Qi7Zlu+ccMHy+Eup5SHsQ==\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n",
            "CertIssuerSubject": "MBMxETAPBgNVBAMTCHN3YXJtLWNh",
            "CertIssuerPublicKey": "MFkwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcDQgAEpne25SHV9u+wGtHEKv/ZCkrjZRcofXXhjnFQ2MJ2hUvuwM0mc+oeEZqxtdly5hJ/igU9dq7US6rKj+UcVyfROg=="
        }
    },
    "Status": {
        "State": "ready",
        "Addr": "manager-machine-ip"
    },
    "ManagerStatus": {
        "Leader": true,
        "Reachability": "reachable",
        "Addr": "manager-machine-ip:2377"
    }
}
]
```

**Docker network inspect on traefik-public**

```
[
    {
        "Name": "traefik-public",
        "Id": "6655p8lsxjmhqhha3e3fbs5xz",
        "Created": "2019-04-21T06:07:01.862111049Z",
        "Scope": "swarm",
        "Driver": "overlay",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "10.0.12.0/24",
                    "Gateway": "10.0.12.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
    "Containers": { .. },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
    "Options": {
            "com.docker.network.driver.overlay.vxlanid_list": "4109"
        },
        "Labels": {},
        "Peers": [...]
    }
]
```

**Problem**

Running services on manager node works fine, but worker nodes return **Error 502 Bad Gateway**